# 16.04 LTS WiFi Not Working, No Hard/Soft Block

Tags: 16.04

I recently got an Acer e5-573 with a Qualcomm Atheros wireless card.  Ethernet works fine, but no wireless networks are detected.  There's no hard or soft block on the wireless.  Any help would be awesome :)  The pastebin with the network info is below.

http://pastebin.com/HQdZ3t5V